# Iris Dataset - Machine learning classification model

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I have training data set in data frame format. Below is just for understanding purpose.

Training Data Set:-

```
 column Names = [SepalL,SepalW,PetalL,PetalW,Species]
 Training Data Set 1 = [5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa]
 Training Data Set 2 = [4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa]
 Training Data Set 3 = [4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-veriscolor]
 Training Data Set 4 = [4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-versicolor]
 Training Data Set 5 = [5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-verginica]
```

Is there any way to consider the column values of training data according to test data , when test data with lesser no.of column values compared to training data?

```
Test Data Set1 Cols = [PetalL,PetalW]
Test Data Set1 = [1.1,0.1]

Test Data Set2 Cols = [SepalL,SepalW,PetalL]
Test Data Set2 = [5.1,3.9,1.4]
```

Comment: You could try to **impute** the missing values.

Answer (score 1):

This will decrease the accuracy of your model I believe. The best way would be to train a few models, each one with 1 or 2 missing columns. Or you could try to impute some missing values with one of the methods [here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/seven-ways-to-make-up-data-common-methods-to-imputing-missing-data/), but note that this will not give you the accuracy that your model would originally get with the same format of the data that it was trained on.

Answer (score 1):

kNN models don't handle missing values by default.

If you are using the sklearn model, you should see a failure when using less features, indicating that there is a mismatch in the number of features. The reason is that the k centroids for the models are made based on all the features. For the few features you have, maybe all centroids are the same.

If you have missing values in your training set as well, you may want to chose another algorithm that handles missing values by construction.

Comment: Could you suggest models which can handle missing values efficiently for the same problem?